# NativeScript app broken after mobile OS upgrade

Tags: nativescript

My team developed an Android and iOS app using the NativeScript platform. The app was working fine on users' mobile devices for over a year now. Recently, when the iOS was upgraded to iOS 13 and Android updated with latest patches on some mobile devices, the app stopped working. The first screen in the app is the login screen. The users could not login to the app. We had to upgrade the NativeScript platform to the latest release for the app to work again. My question - is this the usual cycle - when the mobile OS/patch is updated, the app already installed on users' mobile devices would break - until the app is upgraded to the latest NativeScript update?
Answers are appreciated as our team's mobile strategy is dependent on this behavior.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not common. It was kind of a big deal when this happened with iOS 13; a **lot** of apps broke, not just NativeScript ones.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hope the apps built with NativeScript do not break on every OS/mobile patch update. Has anyone experienced similar issues?